# execfile in it's working directory from other file

Tags: python, python-import, working-directory, execfile

I have structure like this:

```
c
|-myMain.py
|-.....\someDir
              |-startup.py
              |-subDir
                     |-x.py
```

I've found few similar questions, and answers bring me to this:

```
#myMain.py
import os
if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.chdir("c:\\......\\someDir")
    execfile("startup.py")

#startup.py
from subDir import x
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x.doSomething()
```

Problem is that import fails in startup.py when I run myMain.py:

```
ImportError: No module named subDir
```

but, it works when I run startup.py directly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `subDir` have a `__init__.py` file?

Comment: FWIW, you could avoid having to do the `chdir()` to a hardcoded fully qualified path with something like `STARTUP_FILE = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'someDir', 'startup.py')` followed by `execfile(STARTUP_FILE)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for python to see `subDir` as a valid python structure, you must make it a [package](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages). You make it a package by including a `__init__.py` file in that directory. The file can be empty.

Once `subDir` has such a file, the statement `from subDir import x` should work.

Comment: Ok, it works now, but I've also had to add path to someDir as @martineau suggested

Answer (score 0):

Future readers:

Pradyumna's answer [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14094933/7656164) solved this issue for me:

> import sys, change "sys.path" by appending the path during run
>   time,then import the module that will help

[i.e. sys.path.append(execfile's directory)]