# How to run a Python file not in directory from another Python file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec

Let's say I have a file foo.py, and within the file I want to execute a file bar.py. But, bar.py isn't in the same directory as foo.py, it's in a subdirectory call baz. Will `execfile` work? What about `os.system`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add an empty `__init__.py` file to signal `baz` is a module and, from `foo.py` do:

```
from baz import bar
```

Unless, of course, you have a good reason not to make `baz` into a module (and use execfile).

Answer (score 2):

import sys,
change "sys.path" by appending the path during run time,then import the module that will help

Answer (score 1):

Question implies that you want to run these as scripts, so yes: you could use execfile in 2.X or [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/subprocess.html) (call the interpreter and pass the script as an argument). You just need to provide absolute paths to the files.

```
# Python 2.X only!
execfile ('c:/python/scripts/foo/baz/baz.py')
```

Doing it that literally is brittle, of course. If baz is always a subirectory of foo you could derive it from foo's **file**:

```
baz_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "baz")
baz_file = os.path.join(baz_dir, "baz.py")
execfile(baz_file)
```

If both files are in locations that can be seen by your python -- ie, the folders are in [sys.path](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) or have been added to the search path using [site](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) you can import baz from foo and call it's functions directly. If you need to actually act on information from baz, instead of just triggering an action, this is a better way to go.  [As long as there is an **init**.py in each folder](http://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) You could just do

```
import baz
baz.do_a_function_defined_in_baz()
```